# Cant save configuration in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, backend

When I edit something in system -> configuration, it doesn't matter where, for example i want to edit the store contact address, it doesnt save my edit.

I can change and add products but I cant edit anything in the configuration.

The System log and exception log are empty and no errors are shown.
Is says "The configuration has been saved."

Does someone know how to fix this.

Magento version: 1.9.3.6

EDIT:
I have noticed that this problem has occurred when we applied patch SUPEE 11219 When i revert that patch we can save config in the backend again.
Any idea?

Comment: in this patch which system.xml files are updated?

Comment: I dont see any edited system.xml our the git repo

Comment: would you be able to open your browser console and if there is any red message to screenshot the message.. console and network tab can also be useful

Comment: looks like all our answers are not pinpointing your issue accurately as the origin with the error can be varied, happy to take a look if you provide a public url and temporary admin password that may be restricted to config area (and you'll need to have a database backup). ideally, the envrionment would be dev

Answer (score 2):

You need to check "max_input_vars" in your php configuration. Try to increase "max_input_vars" value and test.

```
ini_set('max_input_vars','5000' );
```

You need to set it with php.ini or .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

navigate to

**app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml**

**Find**

```
<log>
    <active>0</active>
    <file>system.log</file>
    <exception_file>exception.log</exception_file>
</log>
```

**Replace**

```
<log>
    <active>1</active>
    <file>system.log</file>
    <exception_file>exception.log</exception_file>
</log>
```

**Note: this is not a solution this will help you in getting the error then once you know the error kindly update the question with the error details**

Comment: I have changed the config of the file you mentioned. we sadly dont get anything in the logging. There is 1 error but i dont think its related to the backend issue.
The error is:  Array to string conversion  in /data/web/public/lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 1849

Comment: did u flush the cache?

Comment: Yes i did flush the cache

Answer (score 0):

In your magento root folder, there is `index.php` file,
In that file the code like this one

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Form that code, remove the # from this line :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

So your code look like this one:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    }
    
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Now open the admin and try to save the config, this will show real error if there anythnig.